# UltiSnips not completing all the placeholders

Tags: vim, ultisnips

How to write a simple snippet where the placeholder value is replaced at both places.

```
snippet test "test struct" 
type ${1} struct {
    id string
}

func (p *${1}) Id() string {
    return p.id
}

endsnippet
```

so when I type test`<tab>`, it needs to prompt for entering one value which results in (if I enter xyz)

```
type xyz struct {
        id string
    }

    func (p *xyz) Id() string {
        return p.id
    }
```

there could be a conflict with other plugins in my system, but currently when I trigger the snippet, cursor moves to second placeholder (at `func (p *${1}) Id() string {`), and never completes the first one.

Comment: I don't know ultisnip, but in snipMate, you'd have to write `type ${1:}` (note the `:`) to get a stop that mirrors text.

Comment: thanks.. tried with the colon.. results the same..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the braces around the second `{1}` (and, maybe, add default text to the first placeholder as pointed out by Ingo Karkat):

```
snippet test "test struct" 
type ${1:foo} struct {
    id string
}

func (p *$1) Id() string {
    return p.id
}

endsnippet
```